# Convert gremlin query to cypher query

Tags: cypher, gremlin

In the gremlin query, use id to query the neighbor nodes of the current node and make some restrictions, for example, limit the number of neighbor nodes to 4, and the search distance is 1-4

```
g.V(2)
.store("v")
.repeat(
    bothE()
    .limit(4)
    .store("e")
    .subgraph("sg")
    .otherV()
    .store("v"))
.times(4)
.cap("v")
.unfold()
```

I converted it into a cypher query

```
match (n) where id(n) = 2
return n as v, null as e
union all
unwind range(1, 4) as _
CALL {
    optional match p=(v)-[r]-(m)
    with *, count(p) as psz where psz > 5
    with nodes(p) as v, relationships(p) as e
    return v, e
}

return v, e
```

Only the node with id 2 in the returned result.

Comment: It is not clear from the query or question what are you trying to achieve. both of your gremlin and cypher query doesn't seem to be doing same thing.
Are you trying to get all neighbor nodes of node with ID 2 up to a distance of 4 ? 

From your gremlin query it looks like you are looking for 4 nodes at distance ranging from 1 - 4. Is that what you are looking for ?

Comment: I want to query the neighbor nodes of this node based on the node id, butI don't know where the problem occurred in the cypher query, the gremlin query is only part of the query.

Comment: if neighbors is all you are looking for then why does this not work for you: 
 MATCH(n)-[*]-(m) WHERE ID(n)=2 RETURN m